# Cannot access disposed object MemoryCache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, in-memory-cache

I'm trying to use IMemoryCache in Minimal API actions in .NET 8 like this:

```
public static async Task<Results<Accepted, ProblemHttpResult>> GetUpdates(
    [FromServices] IMemoryCache memoryCache,
    HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);
        string updates = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var list = // convert updates to list object

        memoryCache.Set("Updates", list);

        return TypedResults.Accepted("/");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return TypedResults.Problem(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

It was working fine before, changed DBContext from Singleton to Scoped due to some problems and after that I'm having this problem while trying to use memory cache.

Using IMemoryCache to store a list of objects and they'll be retrieved in AutoMapper mapping profile (that field needs to be updated frequently).

Tried using IMemoryCache as scoped, it didn't throw any errors but when getting IMemoryCache instance in mapping profile class, it doesn't contain anything.

Comment: As a possibility, if your change in DbContext made it asynchronous, then `memoryCache.Set("Updates", list);` may not block and would require an **await** to properly execute, or may require an async method call depending on implementation.

Comment: Can't use DbContext as Singleton if you mean this.
Having multiple queries in some services and getting problems while using DbContext as Singleton.
But yes my db changes are asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

You say the problem started when you changed the dbcontext setup, but the code shown *doesn't show a dbcontext*. I therefore presume that this is used in the code marked `convert updates to list object`.

I'm guessing the problem here is that your list contains database objects that are connected to the dbcontext, perhaps using deferred loading; if a dbcontext-bound object is cached, it will outlive the dbcontext, and any delayed loads will fail with the symptom described. So: *don't do that*. Only cache simple POCO types that are entirely detached from any complex loading APIs. And ideally: immutable, so you can't get problems with competing requests changing the shared instance.

Comment: No GetUpdates method has no usage of DbContext. converting updates to list is an object mapping procedure (like formatting DateTime objects and etc.) and doesn't have any I/O on database.
My list is a simple POCO type with a few standard type fields like int, DateTime and string.

Comment: @KazemMa k, then to help you *we really need to see that code* (`// convert updates to list object`) - the details matter, and we aren't psychic; my next speculation might be "unmaterialized LINQ" - i.e. the `list` that you have is actually an `IEnumerable<T>` (for some `T`) or similar, that has not yet been evaluated, but: guessing is pointless; **show us the relevant code**

Comment: @KazemMa - Marc is entirely correct here, I would also assume that something wasn't enumerated. Please edit your question with the relevant code so you can get your issue resolved.

Comment: @TravisJ - Thank you all but fixed the bug in another way.
Just removed caching and used another methods, no caching or storing data anywhere .
Retrieving needed data in the end function.